# Trigger a view to render after model changed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

In backbone you can do the following:

```
model.trigger("destroy", model);
```

And it will delete the model from the collection and render the view.  I am trying to get the same effect when changing an attribute on a model.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention in backbone is that the view has a render method which you can trigger as a callback to any of their built in events, your own events, or whenever you would like really.

Typically I have some code like this in the view's initialize method:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render, this);
this.listenTo(this.model, 'remove destroy', this.close, this);
```

You can also have the render call on a change to a specific attribute, here is a sample of getting a view to re-render when the model's age attribute changes:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:age', this.render, this);
```

Somewhere else the render function would be triggered after something like this:

```
model.set({ age: 27 });
```

For more on the built-in backbone events take a look at [their documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).

Here is a [sample fiddle of a model change triggering a render](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyNovo/sSNa7/).

Comment: Would that be in the view for each individual model or in the collection View?  And would I have to call model.trigger("change") for that to work?

Comment: In my sample code it is for the model's view, but if you wanted any view to listen to any model you just use

    view.listenTo(model, "event", view.render);

You do not have to trigger the built in events that backbone provides, they are automatically triggered by certain actions.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle showing a model change triggering a render.

Answer (score 1):

Marionette's Views have [built-in constructs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#modelevents-and-collectionevents) which prevent you from having to write this sort of *Backbone boilerplate*.

```
Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    collectionEvents: {
        "change": "render"
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GcRgG/3/)